# Dismiss UIPopOverPresentationcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipopovercontroller

I have class ViewControllerA from which i present a `UIPopoverPresentationcontroller` which display's data from class B, Which works fine. When i select a value in pop Over i want to dismiss it. My code is as below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *getLang=[self.myArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([getLang isEqualToString:@"Ragul"]) {
        getLang=@"Received";
    }
    else if ([getLang isEqualToString:@"Gokul"])
    {
    getLang=@"Denied";
    }
    ViewControllerA *viewCont=[[ViewControllerA alloc]init];
    viewCont.delegate=self;
    [self  dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [viewCont anOptionalMethod:getLang];
}
```

anOptionalMethod is a custom delegate method which i call to show data with the value selected from PopOver.

```
-(void)anOptionalMethod:(NSString *)langLocal
 { 
    [self viewDidLoad]; 
    self.popController.delegate = self; 
    [self.ContPop dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.langShown=YES; 
    lblText.Text=MyValue; 
    [self.view addSubview:lblText]; // This calls viewDidLoad method 
}
```

When i add the result to the `ViewControllerA` with `[Self.view addSubview:MyValue]` the `viewDidLoad` method is called. So this should not happen. I know that `popOverPresentationController` acts as parent view and so i'm getting this problem. So please help me to solve this.
ThankYou in advance..

Comment: try calling `anOptionalMethod delegate` before you dismiss the `view controller`... & show `anOptionalMethod` method to clear how you are passing `MyValue` to `ViewControllerA`..

Comment: -(void)anOptionalMethod:(NSString *)langLocal
{
   
    [self.popOverController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        self.langShown=YES;
    [self];
    
}

Comment: sorry that was wrong.. Find the code as below

Comment: -(void)anOptionalMethod:(NSString *)langLocal
{
    [self viewDidLoad];
    self.popController.delegate = self;
    [self.ContPop dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.langShown=YES;
    lblText.Text=MyValue;
    [self.view addSubview:lblText]; // This calls viewDidLoad method
    
}
 [self.view addSubview:lblText] calls the viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 10):

To dismiss `UIPopoverPresentationcontroller` programatically,

```
  [[vc presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It might help to note that `vc` in this example refers to the view controller that is being presented in the popup.